# App Store не принимает приложение , ругается на язык

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app

AppStore не принимает приложение , ругается на Язык , и не отмечает где именно ошибка. Все заполнено правильно , может дело в скриншотах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ниже по странице точно нет никаких указаний на ошибку?

Comment: вообще , когда были ошибки он их обознчал , но тут без ничего

Comment: а цену то поставил? такая ошибка бывает, если нет цены приложения - поставь цену или бесплатно

Comment: цену поставил , там стоит 0 , все перепроверил , даже имя пользователя на русском , но когда использовал дополнительно английский язык , он на него не ругался , только на русский

Comment: нууу тогда последнее - все таки по всем вкладкам скриншотов пройди - зайди в  5.5 дюймов и дальше - может какая-то из вкладок что-то скажет

Comment: Вообще без излишних намеков на какие - либо ошибки , написал в центр поддержки , посмотрим что ответят

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в том что я указал devices:universal а не iphone , но странно то что он не ругался на скриншоты планшетной версии